# How to filter data between 2 dates with awk in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, date, awk, gnu

Hi I have the following log file structure:

```
####<19-Jan-2015 07:16:47 o'clock UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <example.com>
####<20-Jan-2015 07:16:43 o'clock UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <example2.com>
####<21-Jan-2015 07:16:48 o'clock UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <example3.com>
```

How can I filter this file by a date interval, for example:
Show all data between 19'th and 20'th of January 2015

I tried to use `awk` but I have problems converting `19-Jan-2015` to `2015-01-19` to continue comparison  of dates.

Comment: `man gawk` and check function `mktime()` for conveting. Or using external `date` to give you awk comparable values.

Comment: mktime(datespec) datespec, is a string of the form "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"    in my case I have no month number just Jan  :(

Comment: You can make a table like `m["Jan"]=1` in Begin block.

Comment: @triplee the date is in a different format so I don't think that duplicate is applicable, although i'm sure i've seen a similar format question before...

Comment: Parsing the date into a standard format may well be a legitimate question in its own right, but beyond that, this is a very common FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

For an oddball date format like that, I'd outsource the date parsing to the `date` utility.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Formats the timestamp as a number, so that higher numbers represent
# a later timestamp. This will not handle the time zone because date
# can't handle the o'clock notation. I hope all your timestamps use the
# same time zone, otherwise you'll have to hack support for it in here.
function datefmt(d) {
  # make d compatible with singly-quoted shell strings
  gsub(/'/, "'\\''", d)

  # then run the date command and get its output
  command = "date -d '" d "' +%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
  command | getline result
  close(command)

  # that's our result.
  return result;
}

BEGIN {
  # Field separator, so the part of the timestamp we'll parse is in $2 and $3
  FS = "[< >]+"

  # start, end set here.
  start = datefmt("19-Jan-2015 00:00:00")
  end   = datefmt("20-Jan-2015 23:59:59")
}

{
  # convert the timestamp into an easily comparable format
  stamp = datefmt($2 " " $3)

  # then print only lines in which the time stamp is in the range.
  if(stamp >= start && stamp <= end) {
    print
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the file is example.txt, the the below script should work

```
 for i in `awk -F'<' {'print $2'} example.txt| awk {'print $1"_"$2'}`; do date=`echo $i | sed 's/_/ /g'`;  dunix=`date -d "$date" +%s`; if [[ (($dunix -ge 1421605800)) && (($dunix -le 1421778599)) ]]; then  grep "$date" example.txt;fi;  done
```

The script just converts the time provided in to unix timestamp, then compares the time and print the lines that meets the condition from the file.

Comment: The idea has some merit, but using two Awks to print the output in a format you cannot directly use is incredibly clumsy.

Answer (score 2):

Using string comparisons jwill be faster than creating date objects:

```
awk -F '<' '
    {split($2, d, /[- ]/)} 
    d[3]=="2015" && d[2]=="Jan" && 19<=d[1] && d[1]<=20
' file
```

Comment: What if it was between feb and jan ?

Comment: How does this have two upvotes when it is extremely limited in what it can do and has no explanation but wintermutes has 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way using mktime all in awk

```
awk '

BEGIN{
        From=mktime("2015 01 19 00 00 00")
        To=mktime("2015 01 20 00 00 00")
}
{Time=0}
match($0,/<([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/,a){
        split(a[1],b,"-")
        split(a[2],c,":")
        b[2]=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",b[2])+2)/3
        Time=mktime(b[3]" "b[2]" "b[1]" "c[1]" "c[2]" "c[3])
}
Time<To&&Time>From

' file
```

---

#### Output

```
####<19-Jan-2015 07:16:47 o'clock UTC> <Notice> <Stdout> <example.com>
```

---

#### How it works

```
BEGIN{
        From=mktime("2015 01 19 00 00 00")
        To=mktime("2015 01 20 00 00 00")
}
```

Before processing the lines set the dates To and From where the data we want will be between the two.
This format is required for `mktime` to work.
The format is `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS`.

```
{time=0}
```

Reset time so further lines that don't match are not printed

```
match($0,/<([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/,a)
```

Matches the first two words after the `<` and stores them in a.
Executes the next block if this is successful.

```
    split(a[1],b,"-")
    split(a[2],c,":")
```

Splits the date and time into individual numbers/Month.

```
b[2]=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",b[2])+2)/3
```

Converts month to number using the fact that all of them are three characters and then dividing by 3.

```
 Time=mktime(b[3]" "b[2]" "b[1]" "c[1]" "c[2]" "c[3])
```

makes time with collected values

```
Time<To&&Time>From
```

if the time is more than `From` and less than `To` it is inside the desired range and the default action for awk is to print.

---

#### Resources

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html